# Export and import foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

We've tranfered a site to a new server and now it's been running for three days without any foreign keys being active.

How can I:

1. Export the foreign keys from the old structure (100+ tables)
2. Import the keys while ignoring integrity problems
3. Discard all the records where the foreign key are missing

Comment: Did you look at mysqldump?? I transfered (a rather small) db entry for entry successfully using this without any integrity problems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create two dumps (current/imported) and use a database diff tool, or generate the alter table statements by pulling the data from the information schema.
2. `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` to disable, `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` to enable.
3. Use left join statements and search for null values in the outer table.

Comment: Great, the foreign keys were all at the end of the dumo, so that's all I needed for 1 and 2, in the case of 3, this has to be done manually for all 100+ keys?

Comment: the statement depends on the tables, but in essence `select tbl1.tbl1_id from tbl1 left join tbl2 on ... where tbl2.tbl2_id is null`